# Unable to add device 'mydevice' because the team has already reached the maximum number of iPhone devices

Tags: ios, xcode

i don't know why
my Provisioning Profiles just my device
but in xcode can not find my device

Comment: are you using xcode 8 onward ?

Comment: You are only allows a maximum number of device in your profile. Once this number reached you will not be able to add new devices. You will need to remove device no longer in use and then wait until you will have to renew you profile. Only after renewal will the removed device be take from the max number of registered devices.

Comment: @SagarShirbhate yes

Comment: @rckoenes how to remove device,i just disable them, and create provisioning profile only add my device,but it's doesn't work

Comment: You can only remove the disabled device once your provisioning os about the expire and you renew your subscriptions.

Comment: just remove some devices from apple developer account .and use auto signing from xcode8. on developer account you can add only 100 devices.

Comment: @SagarShirbhate now, i just 8 devices,but reached the maximum number of iPhone devices,why, personal team?

Comment: @rckoenes i change team,show msg:A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

Comment: i found,whatever i change appids,provisioning profile,my devices doesn't work ,but other devices can run.

Comment: Have you connect(Sync) your device with your itunes (Music)?If Yes so you cant able to add more.limit is 5.